# How to send Html Email using Javamail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an Html Page through javamail from servlet class

Servlet

```
package com.kunal.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CartCheckout
 */
@WebServlet("/CartCheckout")
public class CartCheckout extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CartCheckout() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
                     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                      return new PasswordAuthentication("user","password");  
                     }  
                      });  

            Message message=new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("Receiver"));
            message.setSubject("Agro Test");
            message.setContent(message.setContent("<html>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "<a href=\"http://kunal.blogspot.com\">\n" +
                    "This is a link</a>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>", "text/html"), "text/html");
            Transport.send(message);  
            System.out.println("message sent...."); 
        }
        catch(MessagingException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Stacktrace

```
 Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Agro' did not find a matching property.
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 639 ms
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1391 ms
Sep 02, 2014 1:48:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Cart_Checkout] in context with path [/Agro] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setContent(Object, String) in the type Part is not applicable for the arguments (void, String)

    at com.kunal.servlet.CartCheckout.doPost(CartCheckout.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It gives an error at `message.setContent()`.
The authentication process is done successfully but it generates an error when creating a message.

Comment: `message.setContent(message.setContent`

Comment: Ops!! my bad!!!
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an compiler error look closely to your code you have this

```
message.setContent(message.setContent("<html>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "<a href=\"http://kunal.blogspot.com\">\n" +
                    "This is a link</a>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>", "text/html"), "text/html");
```

it should be

```
message.setContent("<html>\n" +
                        "<body>\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "<a href=\"http://kunal.blogspot.com\">\n" +
                        "This is a link</a>\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "</body>\n" +
                        "</html>", "text/html");
```